# Body moves in circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

If a body moves in circular motion like: a ball attached to a rope or a charge moves in circular motion due to magnetic field

My question is as follows: Why the rotating force doesn't create a vertical component of velocity when the body is at the lowest point?

[image]

Like in this image why the force doesn't pull the body toward the center and make a vertical component toward the center of the circle?

Answer (score 0):

The centripetal force actually gives a vertical component to the velocity.
The idea is that after a time dt, the velocity vector has the following components:
$$
v_x(t+dt) = v_x(t) + a_x dt = v_x(t) 
$$
$$
v_y(t+dt) = v_y(t) + a_y dt = a_y dt
$$
So the velocity vector at $t+dt$ has obtained a vertical component, but still it remains tangent to the circle as $dt \to 0$.

As you can see, besides the vertical component, the new velocity vector still has a $x$ component due to the body inertia.
Therefore the object is not only pulled towards the center, but its inertia still moves it to the right, and the combination of these effect results in a circular motion.

Comment: but if the force result to a vertical component why the speed of particle is constant and always tangent it should have 2 component $v_{x}$ and $v_{y}$ and the magnitude of velocity at any instant should be equal to $\sqrt{v_{x}^2+v_{y}^2}$

Comment: The instantaneous addition of y-velocity is orthogonal to the current velocity, so it doesn't increase the magnitude of the velocity at all. If the acceleration were at an angle, so that some component acted in the direction of the current velocity, then the magnitude would increase. Try differentiating $\frac{d |v|}{dt}$ if the acceleration, $a$, is orthogonal, and you'll see that the derivative is 0.

Comment: @eliyablon 
my question is not about the $v_{x}$ i'm asking about the $v_{y}$ 

if there is a force in the $y$ direction why it don't create a vertical component $v_{y}$
and the total velocity of the moving particle be $\sqrt{v_{x}^2+v_{y}^2}$ 

it didn't add to the $v_{x}$ but it made the particle moves it 2 directions in the $x$ and the $y$

Comment: Good point: I have approximated the acceleration to a constant in the small interval $dt$, but this is in fact not the case, as the acceleration rotates. This would be fully consistent only in the case of constant acceleration, such as in the parabolic motion. However from my simple argument you can understand that the velocity gains a component towards the center, while keeping most of its starting tangential component.

Comment: To see that the speed doesn't change, you can just compute $\frac{d|v|}{dt}$. The variable $|v|$ is the magnitude of the velocity, also known as the speed. So, in your diagram, we have $v_x$ is some non-zero constant, while $v_y$ is zero. When we differentiate, we get $$\frac{d|v|}{dt} = \frac{d \sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}}{dt} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}} \cdot [2v_y \frac{d v_y}{dt} + 2v_x \frac{dv_x}{dt}].$$ However, $[2v_y \frac{d v_y}{dt} + 2v_x \frac{dx}{dt}]$ is zero because $v_y=0$ and $\frac{dx}{dt} = 0$, so $\frac{d|v|}{dt} = 0$, meaning the speed never changes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is vertical speed but its value is zero at the lowest point, yet until it builds its maximum speed the point will be at maximum right position; at this position vertical acceleration is zero and the horizontal acceleration is in action. And this cycle repeats itself

$v(t) = -wr sin(wt) i + wr cos(wt) j$

$a(t) = dv/dt$

$a(t) = -w^2rcos(wt) i - w^2 rsin(wt) j$

$w=2pi/T$

Orbital motion analysis shows velocity and acceleration are always perpendicular to one another

Answer (score 0):

During some parts of the motion, the ball is moving downward, and during other parts, its moving upward. Since the motion is smooth, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there must be some point at which the vertical component of the velocity is zero. As it turns out, this occurs at the highest and lowest points of the circle, which follows from the properties of local extrema of differentiable functions.

Answer (score 0):

> in this image why the force doesn't pull the body toward the center and make a vertical component toward the center of the circle

It does.  Unbalanced forces cause a change in the velocity in their direction, but this does not happen instantaneously – in the same way that releasing a ball from your hand does not cause the ball to *instantly* hit the ground.  You can see in your figure, during the object's trajectory from the 6 o'clock to 3 o'clock position, its y velocity increases consistently from zero to a positive value.   This is a direct result of the y direction force applied to it as shown in your figure. By the time it reaches the 3 o'clock position, the force is completely pointed in the x direction, which is why the y velocity at that point in time stops increasing.

Comment: well but in uniform circular motion the speed always constant if there is a force that accelerating the body why the speed always constant? and why the body always moves tangentially to the curve if the force pulls it why it's direction doesn't curve ? Like if there is a body moving in x-axis direction and a force pulls in y direction the velocity vector gets a y component and the speed changes why this doesn't happen in uniform circular motion ?

Comment: The speed $v=|\vec v|$ is constant, but the y velocity $v_y$ is not. The y direction force accelerates the item, giving it a $v_y$.  To your other question, it is actually a general principle that a force applied at 90 degrees to an object's current velocity will not change its speed, only its direction.

Comment: well let's see that example: if the body at the lowest point and has a $v_{x}$ and a perpendicular force applied on it the speed in the $x$ direction will not change but the speed in $y$ direction will change which will make the body has 2 velocity components which is $v_{x}$ and $v_{y}$ then the total velocity magnitude will be equal to $\sqrt{v_{x}^2+v_{y}^2}$   and the direction of motion will be equal to $tan(\theta)$=$v_{y}/v_{x}$